# Will this lithium ion battery cause too much heat and fry components?

Tags: arduino, batteries, current, lithium-ion, heat

I am looking at this [lithium ion battery](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/DC-12V-Super-Strong-Capacity-4000MAH-Rechargeable-Li-ion-Battery-For-Camera-XP-/232233125141?var=&hash=item36122c4515:m:m-onwwIUgpJdQ-CH4JdcD7Q) from ebay for a project of mine. Its 12v and delivers 1-2A

I am using a [female socket lead to power and gnd wires](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/DC-POWER-SOCKET-FEMALE-12V-12-VOLT-CCTV-CAMERA-CONNECTOR-CABLE-LEAD/322186816780?_trksid=p2141725.c100338.m3726&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20150313114020%26meid%3Da878c5973ef54372acb47c87c3471e55%26pid%3D100338%26rk%3D2%26rkt%3D29%26sd%3D172096944994#shpCntId) for the battery to connect to a breadboard.

I am assuming that the battery will deliver 1-2A and so im a bit scared that it might fry regular prototyping wires, and breadboards and resistors might heat up, will the battery spew out to much amperage and fry everything, is this true and if so what should i do to prevent it, voltage regs?

I am using several power thirsty components: 4 dc motors, arduino mega, 4 hc sr04s, an acceloremeter and 2 light sensors along with a servo motor. The battery should be sufficient for powering these components (let me know if im wrong) but im wondering that if each component requires different voltages should I use voltage regulator for all other components (they all require less) and then hook arduino straight to 12v separately?

Without going into all the numerical specs of each component and judging from the list, how much heat would be generated figuratively and is the battery a good source for the components im using?

Comment: It's impossible to tell without specs from the components, or at least the application of your circuit, we don't know if you're using small DC motors or powerful DC motors, the load they will carry, etc.

Comment: Buy the way, often the question is the opposite: will the components dissipate too much heat and cook the battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that a battery - or any power source - is capable of supplying a certain amount of current does not imply that the circuit in question will *draw* that much current.

Your question puts the cart before the horse. You need to determine how much current your project will draw first. Consider as well not only the average or steady-state current draw, but any surge current (particularly at startup). Once you know that, then you can go back and determine whether a particular power source will work.

Comment: How would i determine how much current is required by looking at the specs of the components

Comment: The easiest way would simply be to use some other power supply of the same voltage to power your circuit through an ammeter, but if the current demand is not steady, this may be more difficult. But in general, take the component likely to draw the most current - like a motor - and check its specifications.